# Why would Type.GetType() work and Assembly.GetType() not work?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to locate a type at runtime from a list of assemblies; my code is something like this:

```
foreach (Assembly assembly in assembliesToSearch)
{
    Type t = assembly.GetType(assemblyName);
    if (t != null)
    {
        return t;
    }
}
```

, and the problem that I have is that t is always coming up as null. Playing around with the debugger and the Intermediate window in VS2010, I noticed the following when I put a breakpoint inside the loop:

```
Type.GetType(typeof(MyNamespace.MyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

works OK, but

```
assembly.GetType(typeof(MyNamespace.MyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

does not (when assembly is the assembly that I know contains the class I'm looking for - in the debugger, I can put a watch on assembly.GetTypes(), browse to the class I'm trying to instantiate, and call assembly.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass, MyNamespace")).

Does anyone know why searching all assemblies using Type.GetType() works, but searching the assembly that I know contains the type using assembly.GetType() does not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the MSDN docs for the two methods, [`Type.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) expects an **assembly-qualified name of a type** whereas [`Assembly.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) expects the **full name of the type**. These are not the same thing.

`typeof(MyNamespace.MyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName` evaluates to an assembly-qualified name of a type (something like `MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral`), so it does not work with the `Assembly.GetType()` call which is expecting a string in the format `MyNamespace.MyClass`.

This is probably down to the fact that when you pass the assembly-qualified name to the `Assembly.GetType()` call, it is looking for a type in the assembly whose full name matches what you have supplied. It cannot find one, so you get a `null` returned. This is not the case with the `Type.GetType()` call as it expects to get an assembly-qualified name of a type and can locate both the assembly and the type.

---

Something to note:

If you are "trying to locate a type at runtime from a list of assemblies" as you say, you are probably better off using the `Assembly.GetType()` call on each assembly in the list and passing in the type's full name. `Type.GetType()` will most likely be using the references of the currently assembly to resolve the type, so if the type exists in an assembly that is not a reference, it will not be found.

Comment: Thanks for the response; my initial code sample doesn't show it clearly, but inside my loop where I'm calling Type t = assembly.GetType(assemblyName), assemblyName is "MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly", so by my reckoning, it ought to be returning the expect Type.

Comment: @David: `MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly` is still an assembly-qualified type name. You need to drop the assembly name from that string for it to work with `Assembly.GetType()`.

Comment: @adrianbanks - where did you learn "Type.GetType() will most likely be using the references of the currently assembly to resolve the type" - it doesn't seem to be in the [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx).  Also, what is the "current assembly"?  In the case I'm looking at now, the assembly with the type - which is found! - isn't the assembly with the currently executed method and isn't a reference of it ... but it _is_ an assembly on the call stack.  (The reason for my question: The Version in my assembly name is wrong but the type is found.)

Comment: I presumed it by thinking about how it might work. It is unlikely that every possible assembly would be searched (e.g. every dll in the GAC plus every dll in the current application's path), so it stands to reason that the assembly's references would be used in the search path. I would take "current assembly" to mean the assembly that contains the type where the `Type.GetType()` is being used. "but it is an assembly on the call stack" - so you mean a reference of a reference? If so, then I would expect that to be found because the type resolver will be doing a recursive reference walk.

Comment: @adrianbanks - Well I mean that the reference goes the wrong way ... the assembly higher on the call stack has a reference to the assembly containing the type that contains the method that is calling `Type.GetType()` - but not the other way around.  I wonder if the answer is in _Essential .NET Volume 1_? (Isn't it a shame that that book never had a 2nd edition or a Volume 2?)

Comment: @adrianbanks - [Here, in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx) there's a note that says `There is no version checking for assemblies without strong names, nor does the runtime check in the global assembly cache for assemblies without strong names.`  So that settles my question.  Thanks!